# i use open sever and when i use jquery, displays error 500 (Internal Server Error). How to fix it?

Tags: laravel

i want to sent data in controller laravel, using jquery and ajax. But when i click on button, displays this error
[image]

here is my code ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });

$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $("#b").bind("click",function ()
   {
       var id = "888";
        $.ajax({
            url:"/insert_",
            mehtod:"get",
            data:{
                id:id
            }
        });
   });
});
```

here is my html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/f.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="b">do it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller code

```
public function data(Request $request)
{
     $student = $request->input('id');
     DB::table("student_table")
         ->where("name","=",$student)->delete();
}
```

here is my web.php code

```
Route::get('/insert_',"StudentController@data");
```

Comment: share your code to send data in controller

Comment: Please provide the code that is making the AJAX call as well as the server code. You may be able to turn error reporting on in Laravel so that you get more information than just a 500 error.

Comment: You should post the laravel logs and relevant code which handles this request along with request sample

Answer (score 0):

I think that the query in the controller is wrong because you are passing the id but then you are using it to retrieve the student's name...
In my opinion, you should change this code

```
...
     $student = $request->input('id');
     DB::table("student_table")
         ->where("name","=",$student)->delete();
...
```

to

```
...
     $student = $request->input('id');
     DB::table("student_table")
         ->where("id","=",$student)->delete();
...
```

The problem is that if the student is not found then is not possible to call the delete method. I hope that this answer could help.